# Stored procedure with header names and using with ajax call with json

Tags: sql, json, header, names

I developed a stored procedure that returns dynamic columns results.
It will be used in AJAX web service and returns JSON as result.

The result will be like

| Attendance | 2021-05-30 | 2021-05-29 | 2021-05-28 | .... |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Present | 200 | 198 | 25 |  |
| Absent | 50 | 52 | 0 |  |

I have already developed the stored procedure which returns dynamic columns based on given two dates.

Now we need to return the result to front-end with header names as json List array.

Please help .

Thanks,
ßhavin.

Comment: Would it not be simpler and easier to return the data with fixed columns like 
 (AttendanceDate, PresentCount, AbsentCount) and then pivot the data as needed in your webservice? What was the reason for developing a procedure that returns dynamic columns?

Comment: which dbms are you using? tag it

Comment: dbms used is sql server 2014 express

Comment: as of now, I solved it out with pivot.js library...